# Large character field sizes in SAS

Tags: mysql, odbc, types, blob, sas

I am trying to import a large blob field from a MySQL table via SAS ODBC passthrough.  The field is larger than the maximum length allowed in SAS.  According to SAS 9.2 documentation character type fields can have a maximum length of 32k. Has anyone had experience storing large character fields in SAS?  Any suggestions other than the obvious one of breaking it down into smaller substrings?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: I'm not sure from your question-- are you saying that your field is, or isn't, larger than 32k?

Comment: Hi Louisa. The blob field I am trying to import from MySQL is larger than 32k.  The maximum field size in SAS is 32k.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, shoot, then I'm stuck too...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blob fields in SAS gets truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919190/blob-fields-in-sas-gets-truncated)

Comment: Voted to close this as there's a newer, more comprehensive Q/A here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919190/blob-fields-in-sas-gets-truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you REALLY do need all 32K of that data to operate on, I would import it into more than one column and use arrays to iterate over those columns any time you need to do processing.

[See RunSubmit.com for more info.](http://www.runsubmit.com/questions/251/large-character-field-sizes-in-sas/252#252)